# How to print the Custom fields values

Tags: custom-field

I am working with genesis theme in wordpress. I am created custom fields using Advance Custom field plugin. Now i want to know that how i can print the fields value into my frontend page ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/#how-to) already?

Seems it would be as simple as`the_field( "text_field" );` where `text_field` is the name of the field ofc.